# WebRTC P2P secure?

Tags: webrtc, p2p

From my understanding Webrtc estabilishes a p2p connection.
So Client A knows the IP of Client b? Isn't this a security risk to expose the ip of another client/enduser?
Shouldn't it instead be routed over a proxy?

Comment: Why would exposing an IP address be a security risk in itself?

Comment: @AKX Check comment on the answer of Wes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposing your IP number is the security equivalent of exposing your telephone number.  It does not give an attacker any useful information about you; it only gives them your location on the network, which could be guessed by random dialing anyway.

Routing all of the traffic through a proxy server means that you need to build a centralized server which can handle all of the traffic simultaneously, completely missing the point of a peer-to-peer service.

Comment: Lets say you want to attack a specific user....

Lets also  assume you have some additional information about a user (e.g. through social engineering) and you know which programms they use whatsoever. Let's say you also know some security risks of these programms running that enables you for RCE.

The only thing you need now is the IP of the other client. Now you invite that person to a Webrtc video conference and get his ip...

Maybe I'm just thinking way to far?

Comment: Sure - all information is valuable in an attack - it's all a question of whether it's useful enough to warrant hiding it.

We make similar decisions every day in life.  Is it safe to put our telephone number in the phone book?  Is it safe to call for a pizza? What if the pizza man is a serial killer and looks up my phone number in the reverse lookup directory? What if I am p2p chatting with a 1337 h4x0r and he sends me a ping of death?

At some point, you have to understand that nothing is absolutely certain.